# Webforms for marketers form fields conditional visibility dynamically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

We are using WFFM for our landing pages creation. It is very easy for our marketing guys to use that. Now, we are looking at customizing them. For instance, we have the following requirement.

On our form, we display country of residence, but when you select some countries, we want to display one more dropdown called `state/province` with the states. When user selects other countries, we have to hide the `state/provice` field. I am banging my head, how can I start implementing this.

Can anyone of you guide me, how to proceed?

Comment: I'm curious if an answer will be given on this one.

Comment: It's hard to believe that WFFM doesn't come with such an option, isn't it? It's such a common thing on almost every marketing form.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Create a `DropList` field on your form in Sitecore
2. Add an Option named something like "NA" (signifying "Not Applicable")
3. Mark the field as required
4. Click on the "Edit" button, under "Rules" in the left pane
5. In the left box, scroll down to the "Fields" category and enter the relevant information into the "where *specific* field *compares to specific value*
6. In the right box, select "hide element", under the "Actions" category

Comment: I just tested with Sitecore 8 and this still works. This was just enough information to get the OP started on right path to create dynamic forms. It is not a complete solution. The instruction above shows how you can use WFFM's built-in rules-engine support to create dynamic forms without writing any additional code.

Comment: Okay. This solution is not working for Sitecore 7.5 (rev. 141003). The rule just seems to do nothing when I change the country drop list.

Comment: I would contact Sitecore support and ask them if this is a bug

Comment: Okay. I contacted support.

Comment: @ADH Did you hear back from sitecore support about this?

Comment: @CharlesBoyung Yes. Here is the response: "Thank you for contacting our support team. From the description provided, I'm not quite sure what is the purpose of such rule - when a form is submitted, it is reloaded anyway, so the "hide element" action just pointless."

Comment: @ADH Ah, so typical response from their support team then. Wonderful.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung I gave support a link to this SO post and posted their response as an answer below. (Was not sure where else to put it.)

Comment: That's pretty irritating. Especially since the "hide element" action isn't a custom action that I added.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel See my comment in ADH's answer below. Unfortunately, it appears that they do not actually support client-side handling of elements with these rules. I came up with a solution to handle this that I'll post either tonight or this weekend.

Comment: The point of this solution is not that it performs the actual hiding of the elements, it is that it disables the validation of the elements so that you can hide the field with client-side code (of your own) without error. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems getting this working on Sitecore 7.5 (rev. 141003).

I have not tried the following instructions out yet, but here is what I eventually was able to get from Sitecore support:

It looks like the reported behavior is caused by the previously registered bug with the 67793 reference number. More information about public reference numbers can be found here: 
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

Please try applying the following patch to see if it helps:

1. Put the attached "Sitecore.Support.401148.dll" assembly into the "\bin" folder.
2. Change the type field values for item information rules(rule content path -> Type field value):

/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item Information/Item ID               ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.ItemIdCondition,Sitecore.Support.401148

/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item Information/Item Name        ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.ItemNameCondition,Sitecore.Support.401148

/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Item Information/Item Template  ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.ItemConditions.WhenTemplateIs,Sitecore.Support.401148

3. Change the type field values for "Fields" rules(the rule content path -> the "Type" field value): 
   /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Fields/Field                                     ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.FieldConditions.WhenField,Sitecore.Support.401148

/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Fields/Field is Empty                     ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.FieldConditions.FieldEmpty,Sitecore.Support.401148

/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Fields/Has Specific Field Type    ->    Sitecore.Support.Rules.Conditions.FieldConditions.WhenHasSpecificFieldType,Sitecore.Support.401148

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is a resolution to this problem at all. I looked at the code using ILSpy and also looked at the javascript included in the WFFM package, and it doesn't appear that there is any client side logic at all. It appears to me that this "Hide element" item is only intended to be used to hide things on the server side, based on criteria already determined before rendering.