# Conditional fields using web forms for marketers?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I need to show/hide a field based on the value entered in another field. The field that is conditionally made visible also needs to be a mandatory field.

Is this possible using WFFM? Will I need to do it using custom fields?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7919088/202

Answer (score 1):

You would need to build a custom complex type to do this. You might be able to re-use existing field types in your custom type, but it would probably be simpler to create them specifically for the new complex type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this and also you can create custom field for this you just simply copy and paste previous one and reflect Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll and see the code how you can achieve this. But I generally use JQuery if I can manage via this